# Laravel - Need to Authenticate with No Password Encryption

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to add authentication to an existing application for a company that has a table that stores its users with plain-text password. In **Laravel**, I know that I can use `Auth::attempt()` in order to authenticate a user, but the password is checked against a hashed password. How to I go about checking a plain-text password instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the password and login user manually with the [`loginUsingId()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#other-authentication-methods) method:

```
if ($user->password === $request->password) {
    auth()->loginUsingId($user->id);
}
```

I'd also recommend you to hash all the passwords. Storing plain text passwords is a terrible thing to do. Do something like this just once (in Tinker, for example):

```
$users = User::all();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    $user->update(['password' => bcrypt($user->password)]);
}
```